# Can't get state of UISwitch when initiated in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I initiate my cellForRowAtIndexPath. It shows up, but when I try to reference it from a different class, it returns `(null)`. If I initiate it in my viewDidLoad, it works but it needs to be in the UITableView.

AddAlbumViewController:

```
// .h
IBOutlet UISwitch *privateSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *privateSwitch;

// .m
@synthesize privateSwitch;

privateSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
[privateSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:privateSwitch];
```

SecondViewController:

```
// .m

TableViewAppDelegate *dataCeter = (TableViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
AddAlbumViewController *addAlbumViewController = [[AddAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddAlbum" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIView *tempView = addAlbumViewController.view;

NSLog(@"privateSwitch: %@", addAlbumViewController.privateSwitch);
```

Please help Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this code:

```
privateSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)];
[privateSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:    UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:privateSwitch];
```

is actually in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, then that code probably hasn't even been called when you're trying to look at privateSwitch. (I'm assuming you read privateSwitch from your new instance of AddAlbumViewController before you try to log it, but you left that code out.)

In your SecondViewController, you are creating a new instance of the AddAlbumViewController and loading that view from the nib, but from the code you posted you haven't actually presented it on screen (unless you left that out?)

Also, btw, you declared a property called privateSwitch but then you're not using it.

Comment: I declared privateSwitch because I needed to read it later. I do use it later when I init it? Also, SecondView contains a UINavigationController and AddAlbum is what's contained in it. The action happens when all the content is loaded.

Comment: But you're not using that property in the code you posted. Maybe post more code? On the other issue, just because the view is loaded doesn't mean the table has been populated with cells. Those are two different things. Put a log or breakpoint in tableView:cellForRow... so you can see when it is called. Also, maybe post more code so people can see the structure of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The tableView IS populated when the button is pressed. I can't think of any more code to post. It's a lot of stuff...

Comment: You sure you don't have two instances of AddAlbumViewController? And how much happens between "UIView *tempView =" and the line were you try to log privateSwitch. And where is the code where you actually read the privateSwitch property?

Comment: I don't have two instances. Nothing else happens between UIView *temp view when I log privateSwitch.The code is in a IBAction that a UIBarButtonItem in the UINavigationController gets.

Comment: OK, I see you edited that NSLog statement to use the actual property now. That makes more sense. But if nothing happens between that tempView line and the log, then there is no way this tableview instance has been populated by then. Assuming those two statements happen one right after the other. The framework does that on the main thread, and doesn't pre-empt your code to populate the table.